# windows, set computer(browser) default web proxy

Tags: .net, windows

I want to be able from .NET to set computer default web proxy (override previous default proxy settings in IE). From the documentation of WebProxy class in .NET it seems that it only affects proxy settings for WebRequest.

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option to play with the registry ([Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/changeproxy1.aspx))

Or you can use API32 for this [Here](http://huddledmasses.org/setting-windows-internet-connection-proxy-from-c/) - recommended

Comment: the Win32 solution works beautifully. It uses WinInet. Thanks !